# Why the transitive closure for this relation $R = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \mid x < y\}$ is R?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I have read a chapter on closures: reflexive, symmetric and transitive, and it seems I have not fully understand the concepts, at least for *transitive closures*.

Why the transitive closure for this relation $R = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \mid x < y\}$ is R?

Comment: Because $R$ is already transitive.

Comment: Yes, exactly; that’s what transitivity of $R$ means.

Comment: Remember, in general the transitive closure of a relation $S$ is the smallest transitive relation $T$ such that $S\subseteq T$. If $S$ is already transitive, then clearly it must be the smallest transitive relation containing $S$: anything smaller wouldn’t contain $S$. And that’s the situation that you have with your $R$: it’s already transitive.

Comment: Yes, it can. You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2):

because it'a transitive by itself